# Create object from line in textfile

Tags: java, object, line

I have a question about creating objects in java. I am new, I am just doing things and then I hope it's working but it's not, unfortunately. I have to create objects from lines in a textfile. I have a peace of code that prints the seperate lines, that already took me a long time even though it's actually not that hard, but now I am stuck. I have 5 lines, each line containing the name of a tv program, begin time, end time, subtitle, etcetera. How can I seperate this lines in to different objects? Objects like program1, program2, program3, with the title and subtitle and times in the object (i put them in the code, I know it's wrong, it just don't know how to do it right). Do you have to create a constructor? (I think you do, but what do you put in the brackets?) A lot of questions, I know, haha:) this is what I have now (it prints the lines, but I tried something with an array, to have the lines seperately in an array (line 1, line 2, 3, 4, 5) but that is also not working..:

```
public class split {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {




 File file = new File("/Users/-/Documents/workspace/opdracht 2/program");
 Scanner scr = new Scanner(file);
 while (scr.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = scr.nextLine();
     String[] array = line.split("\n");
     System.out.println(array);


     }
 split programma1 = new split(String);
 split programma2 = new split(String);
 split programma3 = new split(String);
 split programma4 = new split(String);
 split programma5 = new split(String);
}

 }
```

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first try to create a class which will have the attributes like title, startTime, endTime etc as the instance variables.

You can have a constructor that takes in these variables as parameters or you can go for setter methods which will initialize each member independently.

> 1) Read the line from the file, which represents a TV show.
>
> 2) Create an object of the class mentioned above.
>
> 3) Either pass the parameters in the constructor or call setter
>   methods depending on what approach you have chosen.

From the way you have asked the question, I would suggest you to first go through the basics of Java instead of directly jumping and start programming. Try to understand the concepts and then you would find them easy to apply.

Comment: Thank you for posting useful suggestions and for not posting a direct code solution. 1+ up-vote to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Most important, try to divide the large problem into small steps, and then try to solve each step, one at a time, in isolation if necessary. This is something you should **always** do for large or complex projects, or when doing something new with programming that you're not familiar with yet.
- One of the first things to do: create the fields of your class, including any string, int, or other fields needed. Make them non-static and best if they are private.
- These fields will include String fields for TV program name, perhaps Date fields for the start and end time, although you might want to to leave these as Strings too to keep things simple.
- Next, give your class a decent constructor that accepts all the necessary fields.
- Next in your static main method, work on opening the file and reading through it line by line in a while loop. Test that this works by printing out each line to the screen. Delete the test code after it works.
- Next, split the line (as you appear to be doing) in the while loop.
- Next create an `ArrayList<Split>` (note that class names should begin with an upper case letter). Create this **before** the while loop.
- Next use the array returned by the `String#split(...)` method to fill the parameters of a Split object constructor call, creating a Split object, and placing it into an `ArrayList<Split>`. This is all done **inside** of the while loop.